# Firefox Normal and Firefox Developer Edition from Mozilla PPAs simultaneous via Apt

Tags: apt, package-management, firefox, ppa

I wish to have both Firefox (the normal release) and Firefox Developer Edition (the blue icon version) installed simultaneously, from the offical PPAs Mozilla provide for 22.04 LTS - no snaps for me.

However, both are packaged as "firefox", and thus I end up removing one or the other when I add the PPA.

I think want I want to do is remap a PPA package for apt, is this possible? "firefox" from PPA for developer edition gets mapped to "firefox-dev" thus provide no conflict to "firefox" from the release channel PPA.

Is this possible and how would I configure apt to achieve this? Or perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Why are snaps ideal here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Re-mapping" is not a worthwhile strategy when using deb packages.

- The files are hard-coded, and the package names cannot conflict. Both of those could be (tediously) changed by you...but then the altered package will be overwritten by the next apt upgrade that downloads an updated package.

The much simpler solution is to keep one as a deb, and to install using a non-deb method: Upstream installer, Snap, Flatpack, etc.

If you someday change your mind, snap *channels* can be a super-easy way to switch between ESR, Stable, and Edge versions.

Comment: Thanks. Snaps have had problems communicating with 1password but I've read on another forum that this has changed in a recent version, plus the terrible slow starts until recently, I'll give them another go.